# Triangulating 3d points generated from image

Tags: image-processing, 3d, mesh

Im having trouble generating a decent looking mesh using an image.

Here is an example of an image:

[image]

In my project I convert each pixel to 3d point with its height determined on how far away it is from the center of the line.

Here is what it looks like when I have created a 3d mesh from the image:

[image]

The problem with the mesh is that there are a lot of triangles (and vertices) and it looks really blocky, I triangulate the points just going through the 2d image and joining pixel neighbours in triangles.

Are there any algorithms that could be used to generate something better looking (less triangles / vertices, smoother transition).

Comment: Could marching cubes (or similar algorithms) be decent for this? I browsed some articles about it and it looks really promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just sample both the midline and the boundaries of the white region, and triangulate with a constraint that contiguous vertices of the midline be edges? To preserve shape, the sampling should include all places where midline and boundaries "bend", i.e. all curvature changes.

Comment: I guess this is one solution but wouldn't it reduce the detail of pixels between the midline and the boundaries? Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: What detail? If your metric is distance midline-point-to-closest-point-in-boundary, wouldn't it just grow linearly for every point inside the white band, up to the midline "ridge"?